# div tag float in view when browser scrolls

Tags: php, jquery, html, scroll

I was wondering how to make a div tag float within the screen when a user scrolls down or up on a browser?

For example: yelp.com : http://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=&ns=1&find_loc=los+angeles%2Cca
If you look at their map on the right side, it is fixed in a position but when you scroll down, the map will scroll with you.

Can someone help me?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var $sdiv = $("#mydiv");
$(window).scroll(function() {
    $sdiv.stop().animate({
        "marginTop": ($(window).scrollTop() + 50) + "px"
    }, "slow");
});
```

### Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/N7xqC/

Comment: this is great! haha but is there a way to do it without the animation? and just making it stay on the screen? very simple!

Comment: In that case you don't really have to use jQuery. You can do it with CSS using `position:fixed`. Check http://jsfiddle.net/N7xqC/4/

Comment: Yeah that looks great! But also, is it possible to do it where say you have 50px off the top of the browser right? it will stay in place, until you scroll to the top of the div table and then it will hold in fixed position? Thank you for your help!